# Where can I see my available upvotes for the day?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

I heard [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) and [Joel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) saying that there is like 30 up and down votes available each day for a given user, can I view that number somewhere on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you click at the triangle next to your name at the top of the screen, you will see how many votes you have cast (among other things).